# How to print an array in rivets.js

Tags: javascript, json, rivets.js

I have  data

```
 data = [{
     "task": "get milk",
     "who": "Scott",
     "done": false
 }, {
     "task": "get broccoli",
     "who": "Elisabeth",
     "done": false
 }, {
     "task": "get
 garlic",
     "who": "Trish",
     "done": false
 }, {
     "task": "get
 eggs",
     "who": "Josh",
     "done": true
 }];



 <ul>
    <li data-each-[]="">
    </li>
 <ul>
```

How could i print this data in rivets.js with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below example helps you.

```
<ul id="playersList">
  <li rv-each-player="players">
    <dl>
        <dt>Name:</dt><dd>{ player.name }</dd>
        <dt>Surname:</dt><dd>{ player.surname }</dd>
        <dt>Shirt Number:</dt><dd>{ player.number }</dd>
        <!-- This element will be rendered only if this property will be set -->
        <dd rv-if="player.captain"><b> Captain! </b></dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript :

```
var soccerTeam = [{"number":1,"name":"Gianluigi","surname":"Buffon"},
                  {"number":19,"name":"Gianluca","surname":"Zambrotta"},
                  {"number":5,"name":"Fabio","surname":"Cannavaro","captain":true},
                  {"number":9,"name":"Luca","surname":"Toni"}];

// get the DOM elements
var playersList = document.getElementById('playersList');

// pass the data to the DOM element
rivets.bind(playersList,{players:soccerTeam});
```

Also this link helps you:
http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/rivet-js-backbone-js-made-my-code-awesome/

Comment: but what if array has no name like `var books = [{ title: 'book1' }, { title: 'book2' }, { title: 'book3' }];` and we do not want to bind like `rivets.bind($el,{ books: books })` but we want to bind like this `rivets.bind($el, books);`

Answer (score 1):

the quick way:

```
<ul>
  <li rv-each-data="item">
    <dl>
        <dt>Task:</dt><dd>{ item.task }</dd>
        <dt>Who:</dt><dd>{ item.who}</dd>
        <dt>Done:</dt><dd>{ item.done}</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://rivetsjs.com/docs/guide/#iteration) I think it's `rv-each-item="data"`