# Cannot display values from arrays of JSON objects using rivetJs?

Tags: javascript, json, rivets.js

I am working on a single page application and I am using [Rivet.js](http://rivetsjs.com/) library to bind the data that I fetch from the server to the DOM elements to make the templating of the data easier.

```
$.getJSON('/auth/user', function(response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.roles[0].name);
            rivets.bind($('#profile'), {user: response});
        });
```

Now I can easily access properties in the DOM like { user.first_name } or { user.last_name }

The response contains an array of role objects for the user. When I tried logging it to the console, like `console.log(response.roles[0].name);`, it worked fine, but when I tried { user.roles[0].name } in the DOM, it is not working. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be exactly what you are looking for: binding arrays in rivets

[How to print an array in rivets.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20756539/1508506)